# Load an html file in tails browser while offline?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, browsers, persistent, apparmor

Using tails 2.1, I am trying to open an html file in a browser from persistent storage / or usb drive.

- If I try to open in **Tor browser** (default), it is not loaded at all.
  (I tried disabling all add-ons, experimented with admin, etc).  Strangely, I **can** load some html files, but only those in a specific folder like: `file:///usr/share/doc/tails/website/`
- I tried the **Unsafe Browser**, but the app will not open at all, instead it gives me this error:

> No DNS server was obtained through DHCP or manually configured in NetworkManager

I have disabled all networking as I am using this as an air-gapped system.

Clearly I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a restriction put in place by AppArmor to confine Tor Browser, as such cannot open files in the users home directory or mounted media *except* where explicitly excepted.

For this purpose, there are two folders that can be accessed in the users home directory, defined by these rules in `/etc/apparmor.d/torbrowser`:

```
  owner "@{HOME}/Tor Browser/" rw,
  owner "@{HOME}/Tor Browser/**" rwk,
  owner "@{HOME}/Persistent/Tor Browser/" rw,
  owner "@{HOME}/Persistent/Tor Browser/**" rwk,
```

Similarly, it has exceptions for the Tails documentation/website:

```
  /usr/share/doc/tails/website/ r,
  /usr/share/doc/tails/website/** r,
```

If you want to open a file in Tor Browser from Persistent storage, you should place it in `~/Persistent/Tor Browser/` (i.e. file:///home/amnesia/Persistent/Tor%20Browser/foo.html). Otherwise, it should exist in `~/Tor Browser/` (i.e. file:///home/amesia/Tor%20Browser/foo.html).

Similarly, you would not be able to open the files from external storage in Unsafe Browser (were it even able to launch), as it runs inside a chrooted environment and under a different user, which means it would have no visibility of the files.