# Error in Tails Error opening directory 'home/amnesia'

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, linux

I have setup the persistence volume within Tail (Complete).

Problem: When I download a file it send it asks me where I want to save it. I try to click which where to save example like in Home, and an error comes up saying

```
Could not read the content of the Desktop
Error opening directory'home/amnesia'
Desktop: Permission denied
```

The only place it will let me save is in the Tor Browser.

Then when I try to use the terminal I use the `sudo apt-get install` and the file name which is the `OTRproxy`. Im getting the error

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'file name'
E: Couldn't find any package by regx 'file name'
```

Several things I have tried and have been unsuccessful. I am just trying to be able to execute these files I download from the Tor Browser

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Tails uses `apparmor` to restrict Tor Browser's access to the file system, it can only save files to `~/Tor Browser` or `~/Persistence/Tor Browser`. For more details on this, see my answer [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/14236/12737).

Secondly, `apt` doesn't install by filename. It installs by the package name. `otrproxy` is no longer supported and hasn't seen an update in over 10 years, it's creators warn that it should no longer be used. I would heed their warning.

Beyond that it will not work under Tails, since it has strict firewalling and won't allow you to connect to service outside those it's configured to use or allow. Even if you manage to install `otrproxy`, programs that you run won't be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparmor blocks it. Tor Browser can only access /home/amnesia/Tor Browser/ for security reason.

Comment: It can also access `/home/amnesia/Persistence/Tor Browser/`